# How do I selectively copy rows from a data frame using an array?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have an array with index numbers

```
array=[2,3,4,5,234,653.......2500,2501]
```

I need to copy all rows from DF A with these index numbers(from array) into a new DF

Comment: can't you just loop through the index numbers array, and use the value as the index into the DF array, and the resulting value of the second array you add to a third initially empty DF array?

Answer (score 1):

Easy- use `loc`:

```
# Random array
idx
array([1, 4, 6])

# random dataframe
df
    a
0   1
1   3
2   5
3   7
4   7
5  34
6   3
7  24

new_df = df.loc[idx]
new_df
   a
1  3
4  7
6  3
```

Passing an array to `loc` will select rows where `index` is in the array.